# Selecting rows based on cell value

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, formula, pivot-table

I have setup a pivot table to display some data. In a separate sheet, I would like to show all of the rows in that table based on the value of a cell within the table row. I would like to do this using formulas, but really have no idea how to go about it. I have searched with Google, but I don't seem to be finding or seeing the answers I am looking for.

I would like to do this with a formula rather than have to manually copy and paste the filtered data from the pivot table.

I am using the pivot table as the source data because it provides a grand total. It is this value that I am testing against. I guess technically I could use a SUM() function if there is a way to do this against certain rows like in the pivot table.

This is what I would like to achieve in SQL (this is how I can best describe the query I would like to perform):

> SELECT Name FROM PivotTable WHERE Value1 = 0

**Source Pivot Table:**

```
Name  | Data1 | Value1
Bob   | xyz   | 0
Jones | abc   | 1
Ted   | 123   | 0
```

**Result Sheet:**

```
Name
Bob
Ted
```

Comment: Why are you doing this against a pivot table?  Why not against the original data?  If you add Value1 to the Report Filter, you can then select the value you want to filter.

Comment: @P.Stallworth The pivot table provides a grand total that I want to filter against. Updated question

Comment: I think I'm still a little confused, but if you haven't seen it already, you can use GETPIVOTDATA() to get data stored in a pivot table on another sheet.  You can see it in action by starting a formula then going back to the pivot table sheet and clicking on a row.  The MS reference is [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/getpivotdata-HP005209107.aspx).  Looking at the updated question, when you say you want to "show all rows" that's making me lean towards a VBA answer (or you could link the data in Access and do it in SQL if you are familiar).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filter the PivotTable for Value1 = 0 and copy Name column of table to new sheet.